# WKWebView height change

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, wkwebview

I am using `name='viewport' content='width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=YES' initial-scale='1.0' maximum-scale='1.0' minimum-scale='1.0' user-scalable='no'`
code for `WKWebView` setup.

Is there any possibilities to increase the height the `WKWebView` height?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to make it full screen?

Answer (score 0):

indeed there is a method to increase the size of WKWebView

```
_yourwebview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,400);
```

or while allocation and initation is done set it to a frame that fits, here the views frame the webview is placed inside.

```
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:conf];
```

Comment: Any possibility to setup fixed height according to iOS simulator height?

Comment: yes, just code in `-(void)layoutSubviews {  _webView.frame = self.view.frame; } or .. = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(self.bounds, CGAffineTransformIdentity);` or read more about autolayouting and the different methods to accomplish your idea.